# *Why* does TeX not allow numbers in command names?

Tags: macros, tex-history

I am not asking how the syntax of TeX works. I know perfectly well that only letters are allowed in command names, except for single-character names and constructions using `\csname`. I’m just asking: *Why* did Knuth make this peculiar choice? In almost all other programming languages, I can call my commands `f1` and `f2` and my variables `var1` and `var2`. In TeX, I cannot. Why? What was the intended benefit of this choice?

I know that *if* numbers had been allowed in command names, the syntax would have had to be adjusted in some places, e.g. I would have to write `\kern 5pt` rather than `\kern5pt`. But hey, I actually prefer the former to the latter, so this is hardly a dealbreaker.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124662/discussion-on-question-by-gaussler-why-does-tex-not-allow-numbers-in-command-n).

Answer (score 55):

We can give a surprisingly specific answer: the PDP-10 had 36-bit words.

---

Firstly, note that TeX *does* allow numbers in "commands", in *two* senses. TeX's control sequences are of two kinds:

- A backslash followed by a sequence of letters, like `\TeX` (the control sequence ends when a non-letter is encountered), or
- A backslash followed by a single non-letter, like `\,` or `\!` or `\\` (the control sequence ends after that nonletter).

While many people here have pointed out that by changing the definition of “letter” (assigning the characters 0–9 to category code 11) one can make the digits 0–9 also fall in the first kind of control sequence, note also that even with the default catcodes, TeX allows the ten control sequences `\0` `\1` ... `\9` (of the "single non-letter" kind).

See for instance the source code of *The TeXbook* (search for ``` The following ``rulers'' have been typeset ```…), where Knuth defines the macros `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, `\4` and `\8`, and again near `Inserting spaces according to the table` where he defines `\0`, `\1`, `\2`, `\3` and uses them like `Ord\2Bin\2Ord\3Rel`….

(So if the syntax were to be changed as you suggest, then either `\2Bin` would no longer mean the control sequence "\2" followed by "Bin", or some special additional rules would have to be added e.g. a control sequence containing digits should not start with a digit, etc. And you mention in the question not minding writing `\kern 5pt`, don't forget the very common patterns like `\fam0` or `\box255` which would all have to be rewritten.)

Anyway, to answer your question, you must remember that the initial design of TeX was done as follows:

1. Knuth looked at a (printed) page of TAOCP Vol 2 (typesetting the second edition of which was the original goal of the whole project).
2. He thought about **what he would like to type**, in order to get that typeset output (and which he could also implement easily).
3. He wrote the program to make it happen.

So the syntax of TeX is based more or less on Knuth's personal preferences for input conventions during those early months of 1977, alongside constraints about what was easy/possible to program on the SAIL system available to him at the time. It has been pointed out in the comments that Knuth seems to prefer typing the short form without spaces (it makes sense for him, as he writes his books with pencil on paper, and uses a computer only to type it up at the end). This is reason enough (see the example from `texbook.tex` above), but let's also consider the system constraints of the time.

As far as control sequences go, the very first "Preliminary preliminary description of TEX" [sic] did not even have backslashes — see [`TEXDR.AFT`](https://www.saildart.org/TEXDR.AFT%5B1,DEK%5D) from May 1977 (reprinted as Chapter 24 of the collection [*Digital Typography*](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/dt.html)). At this point, there were just "keywords", as in [`eqn`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/eqn_(software)). But very soon (see [`TEX.ONE`](https://www.saildart.org/TEX.ONE%5B1,DEK%5D) from July 1977, reprinted as Chapter 25 of *Digital Typography*), he had adopted the current approach of using an escape character (backslash by default) for control sequences. All this was before a single line of code had been written.

At this point, he was under the impression that control sequences would not be important / much used. He just needed something that would be easy and efficient to implement, to fit on the machine. He implemented something that was "good enough": Chapter 11 of the SAIL TeX (aka TeX78) manual (included in *TeX and METAFONT: New Directions in Typesetting*), the precursor to *The TeXbook*, had all these rules (**not applicable to current TeX!**):

[image: from Chapter 11 of SAIL TeX78 manual]

The main point here is **"This fact allows TeX to handle control sequences quite efficiently; and TeX's usefulness is not seriously affected"**.

We can figure out the reason for these rules; *how* it allowed TeX to handle control sequences efficiently. The [SAIL language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAIL_(programming_language)) ran on the computers used at Stanford AI Lab ("SAIL"), which were [PDP-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10) (aka DECsystem-10) machines, that had 36-bit words. That is, the machine's native integer type could store any number in [0 … 2^36).

Note here that 2*26^7 < 2^36 < 26^8. That is, with an alphabet of 26 English letters, sequences of up to 7 letters could be made to fit in a word (also distinguishing case of the first letter), while 8 or more letters would not fit. If the 10 digits had also been included in this alphabet, then the alphabet would have had size (26+10)=36, and as 36^7 > 2^36, even sequences of length 7 would not have fit; one would have to limit distinct control sequences to length 6, giving up one whole letter's worth of length just for the small benefit of names like `\some14u` or whatever.

More precisely, the efficient implementation was done in the following way (see the source code, [TEXSYN.SAI](https://www.saildart.org/TEXSYN.SAI%5B1,DEK%5D1)):

> Control sequences, some of which are predeclared, are recorded in a hash table, with an associated table of their equivalent meanings. Linear probing (e.g., Algorithm 6.4L in ACP) is used to access this table […] packed representations of longer control seqences, using six bits for the first letter (in order to distinguish upper and lower case) and five bits for each remaining letter, left justified in the word.

Even at the time of printing of this manual, these restrictions had started to be relaxed: the final Appendix X "Recent extensions to TeX" (starts with *"Stop the presses! The following features were added to TeX just before this manual was printed"*) ends with (the very last words of that TeX78 manual): "Control sequences of any length are now remembered in full; the seven-letter truncation mentioned in Chapter 2 no longer happens".

When TeX was rewritten in Pascal (WEB) during 1980–1982, many of these restrictions were taken away, but the system had been in wide usage by then and the syntax had more or less converged; there was still no perceived need for allowing control sequences mixing letters and digits, and breaking existing usage of control sequences like `\0` and `\1`.

He touches on this at around 42:00 in [this 1982 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoWnTkm4nxs&list=PLABJEFgj0PWWQCiXDJ6UmR8BWQ6YcyVHv&t=2510s) (part of a series about the internal details of TeX82):

> In the SAIL version of TeX… the implementation of strings was quite inefficient: we didn’t want to use SAIL strings for control sequences. Instead we had to go into our dynamic memory and take away valuable space there for the names of control sequences. My first original design of TeX if anybody remembers way back in 1977, I had real strange restrictions that control sequence had to consist of at most five [*he means seven —S*] letters, and upper- and lower-case were not distinguished after the first one, and things like this was all so that I could keep a separate table of my control sequences. I had the idea at first that hardly anybody would be defining new control sequences.
>
> [Audience laughter]
>
> I didn’t realize that macros were going to be very powerful at first... gradually we found that people actually want control sequences so we've made room for them.

Comment: Thank you for your meticulous archaeology!  The TeX I first learned was indeed TeX78, but I've blessedly forgotten the lack of distinction between upper- and lowercase, and the length limit.  This answer is definitive.

Answer (score 35):

Of course, the actual reason why Knuth did this can only be answered by Knuth himself, but we can take a guess based on things we do know:

1. TeX's rules for determining control sequence names are based exclusively on catcodes which makes them easier to describe, slightly faster to implement and more customizable.

   Since TeX already has 16 different catcodes, digits couldn't have gotten their own catcode without adding a fifth bit to the catcode field in tokens. (Which would be a waste since TeX doesn't need 32 catcodes)
   So it could only have been implemented in two ways: Allow `other` tokens in command names or making digits into letters.

   Allowing `other` tokens in command names would be a real pain since you would often accidentally add punctuation characters to your command names, so the more serious version is to make digits letters. But looking at the texbook source or WEB files written by Knuth indicate that he seems to like the existence of `\0` to `\9` as short names for control sequences which don't need to be terminated with a space.
2. Similar to the previous point there also seems to be a much more fundamental reason: You write

   > But hey, I actually prefer the former to the latter, so this is hardly a dealbreaker.

   but all code from Knuth seems to indicate that he feels the opposite: He almost always seems to prefer the shorter form without the space. So while allowing digits in control names might not have many downsides for *you*, it seems to be incompatible with *Knuth's* preferred style.

Comment: Given the very limited memory available when TeX was created, simplicity was a paramount consideration.  Allowing digits to be used for more than one purpose would have required much more code, for very little advantage.

Comment: In effect, the concept of catcodes means the amount of code needed for lexical analysis of the input is tiny, but with the tradeoff of losing some "nice to have" functionality like variable names containing digits.  And efficiency was critical - I can remember running TeX on the original IBM PC where for a document with a fair amount of math, the processing speed was typically one minute per page of output.

Comment: @alephzero -- In its initial Sail implementation, five minutes per page was not unusual.  However, the quality obtained far outpaced what was typical at that time with phototypesetting, never mind the ability to produce math, with input in a language that was already familiar to mathematicians (who were at the same time losing skilled secretarial assistance).  We've been spoiled by the consequences of Moore's Law.

Comment: @alephzero but... come on, _lexical analysis_? That ought to be by far the simplest part of the compilation pipeline, and the amount of work done there utterly negligible compared to the intricacies of paragraph layout and maths typesetting. _Surely_ it would have been no problem to toss in one extra bit for the catcodes.

Comment: @leftaroundabout no you can not toss in an extra bit, tex bit-packs everything everywhere (space was tight:-), if you use one more bit for catcodes you have to use one less bit somewhere else: specifically the catcodes are really just the first 16 entries in the 256 entry table of command codes `@* \[15] The command codes....`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle maybe that is so. But then we should be a bit more clear that all of this is bad software design. It's all great to optimise space usage like this (even if it's “premature”), but it shouldn't be done in a way that bricks the application's future development. If the command code table is so constrained, then it should be _automatically generated_ in some parametrised way, not hard-coded. Knuth has a get-out-of-jail-free card here, but I do feel at least Leslie Lamport or someone should have drawn a line and forked LaTeX away from this mess a bit more.

Comment: @leftaroundabout er latex is _written in tex_   that's like saying someone writing a C program should start by forking the C compiler.  Not to mention that by the time Leslie had stopped working on latex, it still needed to fit into a 540K PC running emtex.  These bit packing constraints are _everywhere_ in tex: that is why you can only have 16 math families or why there are not more math classes or ...  and the question is not, how would it be done now, it's why was it done that way then and I was just pointing out that using 5 bits would be a far from trivial change,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem here is that the distinction between _TeX, the language standard_ and _`tex`, the implementation_ is really meddled. It's like, there was only one C compiler (open source) which had the restriction that there could only be at most 16 variables declared locally in a function. The original writer of the compiler wouldn't extend it further, so everybody ended up using lots of global variables in their projects with inevitably bigger-growing functions. Should some of them have forked the compiler, just to write their program in a better way? _Hell yeah!_

Comment: @leftaroundabout -- Knuth's original assumption was that potential users would do exactly what you suggest: fork the code and adapt it for their own needs.  But in practice, this didn't happen.  Only a few attempts have been successful, and those have been devoted to addressing particular limitations -- fitting it into particular hardware, use of system (or non-Metafont) fonts, direct output to pdf (once that existed and was accepted as a standard), incorporating Lua, ...  It's not as easy as one may think, and few people have independent means of support while doing so.

Answer (score 24):

Given the very limited memory available when TeX was created, simplicity was a paramount consideration. Allowing digits to be used for more than one purpose would have required much more code, for very little advantage.

(This was originally posted as a comment, but since there seems to be some agreement, I'll extend it.)

Tasks that would need to be accommodated in some other way if digits were `\catcode`d to be letters:

- later changes to any `\catcode`s;
- any arithmetic operations, including incrementing counters;
- specifying or resetting any dimensions, including those used to reposition glyphs or blocks of text or other objects.

There are no doubt more, but these alone would destroy the simplicity of recognizing digits for the uses for which they are most appropriate.

**Addendum:**

It must be remembered that the purpose for creating TeX was to make it
possible to typeset *The Art of Computer Programming* (TAOCP) in a
manner consistent with and to the high quality standards exhibited by
the original volumes of the series, set most competently via Monotype.
The design and implementation of TeX achieves that goal.  It was only
later that Knuth was persuaded that making the software available to
others, and in doing so, he accepted suggestions that extended TeX's
capabilities without compromising its original purpose or efficiency.
The last (and most extensive) such extension was the inclusion of natively
accented letters (essentially Latin-1) in 1989, marking version 3.0.

Knuth makes it clear on his [TeX web page](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/abcde.html) that additional extensions
will not be made, and, although such extensions may be made by anyone
who so chooses, the resulting program should be named something other
than "TeX"; that name remains reserved for Knuth's own work.

Comment: I just think there is a tendency that whenever someone asks, “Why is this extremely elementary feature that all other programming languages have not in TeX”, the answer you usually get is that this is *veeeery* difficult to implement. Hey, C is older than TeX, and it doesn’t have this problem. Yes, probably many thousands of lines of code would have to be changed, but are we supposed to pretend that this is not doable, in a manageable amount of time? Certainly, it’s a smaller task than, say, adding Lua to TeX. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler It's not undoable, of course. There is just not enough people with enough free time to devote to a slight change in syntax (that in my opinion would not bring _that_ much of a benefit)

Answer (score 12):

Since the OP seems interested, nonetheless, in how this might be done, I have included a small MWE.  Here, I introduce the `\z` pseudo-environment that will temporarily operate on digits as cat-12, in order to accomplish otherwise painstaking tasks.

I show first how things like `\hspace` and `\numexpr` would be used without the temporary cat-12 digits, and then show again, with the use of `\z...\endz` how they could be alternately employed.  After that, I show how `\z...\endz` can be used for parameterization of `#1`, `#2`, etc., as used inside `\def`s.

To clarify for those wondering, `\z` does operate within a group, and there collects (and thus tokenizes with catcodes) the tokens of the group (with cat-12 digits) into the `\cytoks` token list.  Then, at the end of the environment, instead of performing the customary typesetting of `\the\cytoks`, I instead delay this function until fully exited from the environment group.  Thus, things like `\def` are collected inside the group, but executed outside (and after) the group, so no `\global` is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\xtokcycleenvironment\z
{\whennotprocessingparameter##1{\addcytoks{##1}}}
{\processtoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
{\catcode`\1=12 \catcode`\2=12 \catcode`\3=12 
 \catcode`\4=12 \catcode`\5=12 \catcode`\6=12 
 \catcode`\7=12 \catcode`\8=12 \catcode`\9=12 
 \catcode`\0=12}
{\cytoks\expandafter{\expandafter\cytoks\expandafter{\the\cytoks}}%
  \tcafterenv{\the\cytoks}}
\expandafter\def\csname No1\endcsname{1}
\expandafter\def\csname No2\endcsname{2}
\expandafter\def\csname No3\endcsname{3}
\expandafter\def\csname No4\endcsname{4}
\expandafter\def\csname No5\endcsname{5}
\expandafter\def\csname No6\endcsname{6}
\expandafter\def\csname No7\endcsname{7}
\expandafter\def\csname No8\endcsname{8}
\expandafter\def\csname No9\endcsname{9}
\expandafter\def\csname No0\endcsname{0}
\AtBeginDocument{\z
\catcode`\1=11 
\catcode`\2=11
\catcode`\3=11
\catcode`\4=11
\catcode`\5=11
\catcode`\6=11
\catcode`\7=11
\catcode`\8=11
\catcode`\9=11
\catcode`\0=11
\endz}
\begin{document}

x\hspace{\No1\No2 pt}x
\the\numexpr \No1 + \No2 

%\hspace{12 pt} THIS WILL BREAK, PROVING DIGIT CATCODES =11
x\z\hspace{12pt}\endz x
\z\the\numexpr 1+2 \endz

\hrulefill

\z\def\mymacro#1{x\hspace{#12pt}x \the\numexpr#1 +2}\endz
\mymacro{\No2}

\mymacro{\No3}

\z\def\mymacro#1#2{(#1--#2)}\endz
\mymacro{1}{23}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In The TeXbook I could not find a reason why Knuth made the choice to allow only letters by default. However, he did acknowledge the potential need for more flexible control sequences, and pointed out this can be achieved with `\catcode`.

See the following exercise on page 11, with the solution on page 301 (lines 911-921 in the [TeXbook source](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook)):

[image]

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the TeX book then. How can it be 256^2 if you need at least 1 char with catcode 1 to start it?

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Interesting point. :) Not strictly a bug maybe, as the idea I guess would be to use different escape characters depending on which two characters are in the control sequence you want to refer to. (Like: if you've defined a control sequence made of the two "letters" \ and !, then you can still refer to this specific one using a different escape character say `;`, like `;\!`. Then change catcodes again when you want to use a control sequence containing `;` as a "letter".)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach In my opinion, the bug in the TeXbook might be that by using the word "possible" without clarification the question is not formulated with sufficient precision. The amount of length 3 **possible at a single point in time** indeed is something like (256 - [amount of characters not of catcode 11])^2.   At least one character must be of catcode 0(escape). So in any case at least one character is not of catcode 11. So the largest amount of 3 that is possible at a single point in time is (256 -1)^2 = (255)^2. But if "possible" also subsumes catcode-changes/several points in time...

Comment: @ShreevatsaR you and Ulrich are right, the question would  allow for the escape char to change back and forth (and I should have written catcode 0)

Answer (score 8):

Whereas my other answer takes the approach of actually changing the catcodes of the digits `0`-`9`, we see that it introduces many difficulties that may not be worth the effort.

In contrast, this approach changes no catcodes, but instead uses an active character (here taken as `/` since it looks kind of like `\`, and one can use `\slash` as a text replacement) to act almost like a catcode 0 token, but to include the digits `0`-`9` when both defining as well as invoking "macros".  If you prefer to *sacrifice* a different token than `/`, just replace every instance of `/` in the MWE with the desired active character.  The limitation of this approach, as we shall see, is that the process of tokenizing alphanumeric macro names is not expandable.

The idea came to me from my `tokcycle` package, which is confronted with the challenge of parsing the tokens of an input stream in a single pass.  Two difficult things to do are differentiating a `{` from a `\bgroup` and differentiating a space from an implicit space.  The way `tokcycle` accomplishes this is to take the `\string` of the token.  In the end, `tokcycle` does this to *every* cat-0 control sequence in the input stream as a matter of course.  The problem, then, for those tokens that are now control sequence `\string`s, is reconstituting the macro from which the `\string` originated, since it was a string and not a macro that was initially absorbed.

`tokcycle` uses a macro `\csmk` which performs a faux tokenization of the string (meaning it uses a macro rather than the TeX mouth to tokenize the input stream), but using the rules of control-sequence name construction.  I decided, here, to start with `\csmk`, rename it to `\xsmk`, and adjust it to include digits `0`-`9` as well as cat-11 tokens in the process of faux tokenization.

I then place a wrapper around this macro that uses an active character `/` both to invoke macros defined with this faux tokenization as well as to define them.

The syntax is `/def/<alphanumeric string>{...}` to define a macro that is invoked by way of `/<alphanumeric string>`.  It will even work with delimited arguments. In the MWE, I show examples of these.

Then, purely for demonstration, I revert two definitions used in `\xsmk` so that it behaves in a fashion similar to the original `\csmk` (except operating on cat-11 tokens, instead of cat-12 string tokens).  I then run the same input through and you will see how the faux tokenization excludes digits from the macro names.

In summary then, this approach enables the definition and non-expandable invocation of alphanumeric macro names (which are internally stored as `\csname` constructions) with the use of an active token `/` that functions *as if* it were a catcode-0 `\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}

% FAUX TOKENIZATION BASED ON tokcycle MACRO \csmk
\makeatletter
\def\xsmk#1{\def\xsaftermk{#1}\toks0{}\@xsmkA}
\def\@xsmkA{\futurelet\@tmp\@xsmkB}
\def\@xsmkB{\tctestifx{\@tmp\tc@sptoken}%
  {\toks0{ }\expandafter\@xsmkF\tc@absorbSpace}{\@xsmkCA}}
\def\@xsmkCA#1{\tc@addtoks0{#1}\tctestifnum{\numberCatcode#1=11}%
  {\futurelet\@tmp\@xsmkD}{\@xsmkF}}
\def\@xsmkC#1{\tctestifnum{\numberCatcode#1=11}
  {\tc@addtoks0{#1}\futurelet\@tmp\@xsmkD}{\@xsmkE#1}}
\def\@xsmkD{\tctestifCatnx A\@tmp\@xsmkC\@xsmkE}
\def\@xsmkE{\tctestifx{\@tmp\tc@sptoken}%
  {\expandafter\@xsmkF\tc@absorbSpace}{\@xsmkF}}
\def\@xsmkF{\tc@defx\thecs{\csname\the\toks0\endcsname}\xsaftermk}

\def\tc@addtoks#1#2{\toks#1\expandafter{\the\toks#1 #2}}
\makeatother

% ADJUST TO INCLUDE cat-11 LETTERS AS WELL AS DIGITS 0-9
\def\numberCatcode#1{%
  \tctestifcatnx 1#1
    {\tctestifx{#11}{11}
    {\tctestifx{#12}{11}
    {\tctestifx{#13}{11}
    {\tctestifx{#14}{11}
    {\tctestifx{#15}{11}
    {\tctestifx{#16}{11}
    {\tctestifx{#17}{11}
    {\tctestifx{#18}{11}
    {\tctestifx{#19}{11}
    {\tctestifx{#10}{11}
    {\number\catcode`#1}}}}}}}}}}%
  }{\number\catcode`#1}%
}
\long\def\tctestifCatnx#1#2#3#4{%
  \tctestifcatnx#1#2{#3}%
  {\tctestifx{#21}{#3}
  {\tctestifx{#22}{#3}
  {\tctestifx{#23}{#3}
  {\tctestifx{#24}{#3}
  {\tctestifx{#25}{#3}
  {\tctestifx{#26}{#3}
  {\tctestifx{#27}{#3}
  {\tctestifx{#28}{#3}
  {\tctestifx{#29}{#3}
  {\tctestifx{#20}{#3}{#4}}}}}}}}}}}%
}

% ACTIVE CHARACTER WRAPPER
\catcode`\/=\active
\def/{\xsmk{\parsecs}}
\def\parsecs{\expandafter\tctestifx\expandafter{\thecs\def}{\Qdef}{\thecs}}
\def\Qdef/{\xsmk{\Qdefhelp}}
\def\Qdefhelp{\expandafter\def\csname\the\toks0\endcsname}

% DEFINE SOME WORKING MACROS WITH \def AND /def
\def\1{[1]}
\def\a{[a]}
\def\aa{[aa]}
/def/1a{[1a]}
/def/a3{[a3]}
/def/aa1{[aa1]}
/def/a7a{[a7a]}
/def/b3-#1-{[b3:#1]}% MACRO /b3 WITH DELIMITED -#1- ARGUMENT
\def\b{[b]}

\begin{document}
\def\doit{
/a
/today ,
/a3.
/a3 .
/aa1.
/aa1{}
/1a.
/a7a
/b3-xyz-

\tctestifCatnx AaTF
\tctestifCatnx A.TF
\tctestifCatnx A1TF

\numberCatcode a,
\numberCatcode .,
\numberCatcode 1
}

\doit

RECOVER ORIGINAL TOKENIZATION
\def\numberCatcode{\number\catcode`}
\let\tctestifCatnx\tctestifcatnx

\doit
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case one was wondering in terms of how to adapt `\xsmk` to other uses, the syntax is `\xsmk{<after-code>}<input stream>`.  With such an invocation, a macro name is constructed from the leading tokens of the input stream, using the rules provided, and stored in `\thecs`.  Then, `<after-code>` is executed.

Answer (score 6):

For similar aesthetic reasons that you want to be able to write `\banana5`, Knuth apparently wanted to be able to write `\box4` and `\dimen12`.  Making numbers part of control words would have required writing `\box 4` and `\dimen 12` to achieve the same effect, and when formatting something like `\dimen 12=4pt\relax` this could have been broken across lines at the space.

In particular for writing the TeXbook, this would have caused extra input/formatting work and pain and would have led to awkward reading since plain TeX works a *lot* using registers.  Being able to use pretend-names like `\dimen12` helps to keep it readable, *exactly* for the same reasons that you'd like something like `\banana5` to be a single identifier.

Comment: Alternatively, as @egreg pointed out, `\banana{5}`, `\dimen{12}`, and `\box{4}` would have been a much better syntax.

Comment: @Gaussler -- The problem with your proposal is that it requires a *lot* more typing (at least for input of the TeXbook), and also, in many cases, would require definitions to include an extra argument, a situation that traps a *lot* of TeX newbies with quite incomprehensible errors.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, honestly, for anyone who learned TeX in the 21st century, I think syntax like `\kern5pt` is what is really causing confusion. And do you seriously think that a few braces here and there count as “a *lot* more typing”? If Knuth could spend 10 years on developing TeX, I’m sure he could also add a few braces here and there.

Comment: @Gaussler -- Okay.  Forget the "lot more typing".  With digits allowed in control words and requiring braces in other environments, there are now three distinct syntactic uses for digits, and getting braces around the correct ones requires different thinking patterns.  Most important, it makes debugging a *lot* harder, and for someone in whose profession debugging is central, that makes a difference.  You're welcome to use the TeX code and develop a variant that you like.  (Just don't call it TeX.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good. But I, for one, would have liked to be able to make a control sequence `\C1` for the category `\mathcal{C}_1`. I could, of course, call it `\Cone`, but this one is already taken for the cone construction, and the name is far less intuitive. Don’t get me started on `\projonethree` for the projection `\pi_{13}`. Numbers not being allowed in control sequences is annoying me at least five times a day. Luckily, I have my `stricttex` package which takes care of it, but which unfortunately requires LuaTeX.

Comment: @Gaussler -- I'm glad you've found a package that allows you to do what you want and find convenient.  Just be aware that the *original* TeX will continue to work as is most convenient for Knuth, and software built on that premise (and so advertised) will do the same.  Thus it's possible that sometime that limitation might reach out and bite you in the ankles, and if you need debugging help, be sure to warn potential helpers that you've made this modification.

Answer (score 5):

Multiletter-control-sequences in the .tex-input intended to yield a single *⟨control-word-token⟩* during tokenization are to consist of a single character of category 0(escape) trailed by a (non-empty) sequence of characters of category 11(letter).

Characters that represent decimal digits (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`) usually are assigned category 12(other). Therefore digits usually are not considered parts of names of *⟨control-word-tokens⟩* that come into being directly via tokenizing .tex-input. (*⟨control-word-tokens⟩* coming into being as the result of the toplevel-expansion of `\csname...\endcsname` is a different story.)

**Why at all having TeX distinguish a set of category 11(letter)-characters from a set of category 12(other)-characters instead of having TeX just "look" at the union of these two sets?**

TeXbook, Appendix B: Basic Control Sequences says:

> When INITEX begins, **category 12 (other) has been assigned to all 256
> possible characters, except** that the 52 letters A...Z and a...z are
> category 11 (letter), and a few other assignments equivalent to the
> following have been made:
>
> ```
> \catcode `\\ =0    \catcode`\ =10    \catcode `\% =14
> \catcode`\^^@=9    \catcode`\^^M=5    \catcode`\^^?=15
> ```

A double-dangerous-bend-paragraph of Chapter 7, How TeX reads what you type,  says the same. Chapter 7 also says that token-producing-"operations" like `\string`, `\number`, `\romannumeral` produce character-tokens of category 12(other). The same is for `\the` in many situations.

**To me it seems that category 12(other) is seen as the "standard".**

**To me it seems category 11(letter) was introduced for denoting** (besides characters of category 0-10 and 13-15) **a**nother set of "non-standard"-characters. A **set of** "non-standard"-characters whose properties deviate from the properties of all other **characters** in the aspect **that** only these characters **can be used** within .tex-input **for denoting names of *⟨control-word-tokens⟩***.

**I don't know why Professor Knuth decided for introducing a category for explicitly declaring a set of characters that can be used for denoting names of *⟨control-word-tokens⟩*.**

But I think having such a set of characters defined can be very handy. E.g., for more easily judging whether a sequence of characters forms the name of a *⟨control-word-token⟩* when looking at a piece of TeX-code with one's eyes.

**However, I think that the fact that digit-characters by default are not elements of this set and therefore usually are not considered parts of names of *⟨control-word-tokens⟩* that come into being directly via tokenizing .tex-input is not due to a strong desire to specifically prevent/forbid/dis-allow the usage of digits in names of *⟨control-word-tokens⟩*.**

I suppose digit-characters by default usually not being considered parts of names of *⟨control-word-tokens⟩* that come into being directly via tokenizing .tex-input **is just a side-effect taken for acceptable.**

I suppose the main reason for assigning category 12(other) to digits (and this way—as a "side-effect"—excluding digits from that set of characters that can be used for denoting names of *⟨control-word-tokens⟩*) is:

According to TeXbook, Chapter 24: Summary of Vertical Mode  *⟨digit⟩*-quantities are explicit character-tokens of catcode 12(other)`012|112|212|312|412|512|612|712|812|912` (not catcode 11(letter)! ).

E.g., within macro-definitions a macro-argument is denoted by a category 6(parameter)-character-token that is trailed by such a (category-12-)*⟨digit⟩*-quantity in range 1..9:

```
\catcode`\1=11
\def\foo#1{this is foo}
\bye
```

yields an error-message "`! Parameters must be numbered consecutively`."

**Assigning category 12(other) to digits makes it possible to use them as *⟨digit⟩*-quantities, e.g, for denoting macro-arguments or as components of *⟨(8-bit) number⟩*-quantities.** (*⟨8-bit number⟩*-quantities are a special case of *⟨number⟩*-quantities and they are used with things like `\catcode`).

**Using characters/digits 0 ,1, ..., 9 as *⟨digit⟩*-quantities is not possible if they have category 11(letter).**

**So a sort of reason why you usually cannot use 0, 1, ..., 9 in command names is that assigning them category 11(letter), which is the only way of making it possible to use them in command names,  excludes using them as *⟨digit⟩*-quantities, e.g., in macro-arguments `#1`, `#2`, etc, or as components of *⟨number⟩*-quantities as *⟨digit⟩*-quantities by design must be of category 12(other). Token-producing routines like `\the⟨count-register⟩` and `\number` and `\string` all also produce character-tokens of category 12(other). (Exception: Spaces produced by `\string` are of category 10.)**

I said "a sort of reason" because, given how TeX is implemented, this just explains why switching digits to category 11(letter)—and this way allowing them to be components of the names of control-word-tokens—might cause problems/is not a good idea and why this this is not done by default. But this is not an explanation why TeX is implemented in a way where switching digits to category 11(letter)—and this way allowing them to be components of the names of control-word-tokens—can lead to problems.

Probably it would have been nice to allow *⟨digit⟩*-quantities to be not only of category 12(other) but to be of category 11 also and to assign digits to category 11(letter) by default. But that ship has sailed—e.g., when denoting numbers of registers people in their .tex-input-files omit the space between `\count`/`\box`/`\toks`/`\skip` and the digit-sequence that denotes the number.

---

As under normal category code régime you cannot obtain the *⟨control-word-tokens⟩* `\var1` and `\var2` directly by having TeX read and tokenize .tex-input and as correct invocation of `\csname..\endcsname` in combination with `\expandafter` sometimes seems cumbersome, I offer a macro `\CsNameToCsToken` to create, e.g.,  the *⟨control-word-token⟩* `\var1` from the *⟨character-token⟩*-sequence `v11a11r11112` or the *⟨control-word-token⟩* `\var2` from the *⟨character-token⟩*-sequence `v11a11r11212`.

The phrase "create the *⟨control-word-token⟩*" here doesn't focus that much on defining a macro. The focus is more on the stage of expanding the macro `\CsNameToCsToken` and hereby replacing *⟨character-tokens⟩* nested between curly-brace-tokens (`{1` and `}2`) by a *⟨control-word-token⟩*—be that *⟨control-word-token⟩* defined or not (yet) defined.

`\CsNameToCsToken` does things like `\csname..\endcsname` for you and is intended to prevent you from the need of inserting `\expandafter` and the like in the right places which can be tricky or—depending on your attitude and level of knowledge—painful. It is not a means for directly writing `\var1` or `\var2` within the .tex-input.

Syntax:

`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{⟨NameOfCs⟩}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs`

(`⟨stuff not in braces⟩` may be empty.)

(`⟨stuff not in braces⟩` is treated as `{`-delimited argument via TeX's `#{`-notation.
Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the result is obtained by triggering two expansion-steps, e.g., by having two "hits" with `\expandafter`.)

Examples:

With such a macro you are not bound to specific definition commands:

`\CsNameToCsToken{foo}` → `\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\global\long\outer\def{foo}` → `\global\long\outer\def\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{foo}\bar` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}=\bar` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}={bar}` → `\CsNameToCsToken\let\foo={bar}` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken` might be useful not only with plain TeX. It can as well be applied with LaTeX 2ε- and `xparse`-definition-commands:

`\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{foo}` → `\newcommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\DeclareRobustCommand{foo}` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\NewDocumentCommand{foo}...` → `\NewDocumentCommand\foo...`  .

Using plain TeX, not LaTeX:

```tex
\begingroup
\def\foo#1{#1}%
\catcode`\@=11
\foo{%
  \endgroup
  %%===============================================================================
  %% End \romannumeral-driven expansion safely:
  %%===============================================================================
  \chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00
  %%===============================================================================
  %% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
  %%===============================================================================
  %% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
  %% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
  %% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
  \long\def\InnerCsNameToCsToken#1#2{%
    \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  }%
  \long\def\UD@exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
}%


\begingroup\tt
\noindent Define \string\var1:
\hfill\break
\string\CsNameToCsToken\string\def\string{var1\string}\string{This is the current value of var1.\string}
\endgroup
\CsNameToCsToken\def{var1}{This is the current value of var1.}
\hfill\break\null

\begingroup\tt
\noindent Define \string\var2:
\hfill\break
\string\CsNameToCsToken\string\def\string{var2\string}\string{This is the current value of var2.\string}
\endgroup
\CsNameToCsToken\def{var2}{This is the current value of var2.}
\hfill\break\null

\begingroup\tt
\noindent Using \string\var1/var1: \string\CsNameToCsToken\string{var1\string}
\hfill\break\null\hfill\break\null
\endgroup
\noindent \CsNameToCsToken{var1}
\hfill\break\null

\begingroup\tt
\noindent Using \string\var2/var2: \string\CsNameToCsToken\string{var2\string}
\hfill\break\null\hfill\break\null
\endgroup
\noindent \CsNameToCsToken{var2}

\bye
```

[image]

Using LaTeX:

```latex
\makeatletter
%%===============================================================================
%% End \romannumeral-driven expansion safely:
%%===============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
Define \var1:
\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{var1}{This is the current value of var1.}
\end{verbatim}

\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{var1}{This is the current value of var1.}

\begin{verbatim}
Define \var2:
\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{var2}{This is the current value of var2.}
\end{verbatim}

\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{var2}{This is the current value of var2.}

\begin{verbatim}
Using \var1/var1: \CsNameToCsToken{var1}
\end{verbatim}
\CsNameToCsToken{var1}

\begin{verbatim}
Using \var2/var2: \CsNameToCsToken{var2}
\end{verbatim}
\CsNameToCsToken{var2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the argument here is a bit backwards since if Knuth would have wanted to make digits letters, he could just have changed the scanning rules to accommodate this. It wouldn't have been any more complicated to implement the system with all digits being letters. (The only change would have been to replace `define zero_token = other_token + "0"` with `define zero_token = letter_token + "0"` in the source code)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Would the change lead to token-producing-operations like `\number` and `\the` also producing digits of catcode 11(letter)?  If not, then this would lead to the result of `\number`, which is catcode-12-character-tokens, not being "evaluatable" by `\romannumeral` or another `\number` any more - things like `\romannumeral\number\number#1 000` for obtaining `#1` catcode-12-characters "m"(e.g., with `#1`=`\count11`) wouldn't work out.

Comment: That's an excellent argument. Even if the \the expansion would create letter catcodes for digits it would lead to very messy rules there.

Comment: While there are some good arguments here, they're expressed using LaTeX terminology.  LaTeX diverges in a number of ways from Knuthian TeX, is not used by Knuth, and he has voiced strong disagreement with some LaTeX decisions (though not in the area of how digits are used).  Thus the arguments here are weakened by association.  Still, worth an upvote for the effort.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The example exhibiting `\CsNameToCsToken` is LaTeX, yes, but can easily be adapted to plain TeX. Which other arguments/phrases are LaTeX terminology?

Comment: `\DeclareRobusrCommand` and `\NewDocumentCommand` are LaTeX, and relatively recent at that.  Yes, they can be reduced to basic TeX terminology, but even `\protect`, avoidance of which was one reason for the definition of `\DeclareRobustCommand`, was introduced in LaTeX (equivalent to the primitive `\string`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\DeclareRobustCommand` and `\NewDocumentCommand` are not relevant for the arguments at all. They are used in some examples of how a the command `\CsNameToCsToken` could be applied for defining commands with digits in their names in LaTeX. But there are also 7 examples of applying `\CsNameToCsToken` which do without LaTeX at all. I just added an example, defining exactly the same `\CsNameToCsToken`-command using plain TeX only.

Comment: Yes, that works.  But one can't simply use `\var1` or `\var2`; those have to be accessed by `\csname var1\endcsname`, etc.  (Tested with `\show`: `\expandafter\show\csname var1\endcsname` works, but not just `\show\var1`.)  So not really useful to an ordinary user.  So it does demonstrate that using digits in control names is impractical in the current state of things.  (But it still doesn't directly say *why*, which was the original question.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton In my answer I said that catcode 11 for 0, 1,2,...,9  would break usage of 0, 1,2,...,9 as <digit>-quantities. I think that can be taken for a reason.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The gist of `\CsNameToCsToken` is that you can access `\var1`, `\var2` via `\CsNameToCsToken{var1}`/`\CsNameToCsToken{var2}`. You can use the same command both for defining and just calling/accessing the command. You can do `\CsNameToCsToken{var1}` and it will do `\csname var1\endcsame` -> `\var1` for you. You can do `\CsNameToCsToken\show{var1}`  and it will do `\show\var1` for you. No `\expandafter` needed (as it is used "under the hood") which is a benefit for those who fear `\expandafter`. ;-)

Comment: I misunderstood, thinking that `\var1` could then be accessed directly.  Apologies for dragging this out.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Never mind. :-) For someone like me it is in any case an honor when someone with your knowledge, skills and merits for the TeX community and the AMS addresses the word to him and shows that she takes note of his confused contributions. ;-) I appreciate that you don't hesitate to question things I've written/uttered. With you, as with most of the regulars who write here, I assume that questioning is not meant to be destructive, but to be constructive/helpful.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger But still you are right - the argument indeed in some way is pointless/is a way of saying: It is this way because it was implemented this way. ;-)  Probably it would have been nice to allow ⟨digit⟩-quantities to be not only of category 12 but to be of category 11 also and switching catcodes of digits to 11. But that ship has sailed - e.g., when denoting numbers of registers people omit the space between `\count`/`\box`/`\toks` and the digit-sequence that denotes the number.