# Create programmatically a macro whose name contains the value of a counter

Tags: macros

I often need to define macros whose name contains the value of a counter, notably to attribute a value to multiple objects: in python I would do:

```
myArray[0] = "mystyle"
```

Unfortunately, I can't use `\expandafter\xdef\csname myArray\the\mycounter\endcsname` because in LaTeX, it is not possible to have numbers in macros. For now I'm using `\roman{mycounter}` instead, but it feels very hacky as it can take a long time to computer the roman version of a number... Is there any better solution? I tried notably to check if LaTeX3 provided something better for this kind of associative arrays containing numbers, but I can only find integers arrays (I guess integers that can only contain arrays). The other option I imagine is maybe a sequence of tupples, but then the access time is linear which is not very efficient.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[options]{article}


\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\expandafter\edef\csname myArray\roman{mycounter}\endcsname{Hello}

``Bonjour'' is ``\csname myArray\roman{mycounter}\endcsname''.

\end{document}
```

Comment: since you are using csname you can use digits anyway replace `\roman{mycounter}` with `\themycounter` (or `\arabic{mycounter}`)

Comment: you could use `\expandafter\xdef\csname myArray\the\mycounter\endcsname` if `\mycounter` was defined   (eg by `\newcount\mycounter`)  your code shown doesn't define it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I was not aware of this rule, thanks a lot!

Comment: See these questions: [Creating a command with numbers on it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/627408/118714), [*Why* does TeX not allow numbers in command names?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598250/118714), [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718/118714), [Command/macro name cannot include numbers and symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66666/118714).

Comment: `\csname foo17$_B\endcsname` 's replacement text is the control-word-token `\foo17$_B`. Expandable tokens, e.g. `\the\mycounter`, between `\csname` and `\endcsname` are expanded. In expl3-syntax you can use `\use:c` instead of `\csname..\endcsname`.  You might be interested in [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380/118714)

Comment: Nice, I would not expect csname to work for any strange macro name ^^ Thanks!

Comment: the macro name is not strange and it's not really a fearure of csname for example after `\catcode\`1=11`  you could use `\def\zz11{abc}`   and use `\zz11`  but if you restore the catcode of 1 you would need csname again as `\zz11` would parse as `\zz 1 1`  the restriction about digits is not a restriction on allowed names, it is just a feature of how input characters are parsed into tokens

Comment: @tobiasBora There is nothing strange about these macro names. :-) About category codes of characters: Category 11(letter) just denotes the set of characters whose elements **at the time of tokenizing** .tex-input might be taken for components of the name of a multiletter-control-sequence/of a control-word-token. But tokenization of .tex-input is not the only way in which tokens come into being. E.g. there is nothing against having TeX create control-word-tokens from a set of (explicit) character tokens via `\csname..\endcsname`  when tokenization of .tex-input is already done.

Comment: Ok thanks everybody, it's much clearer now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\cs#1{\csname#1\endcsname}
```

then an equivalent of python's

```
myArray[0] = "mystyle"
```

is

```
\sdef{myArray[0]}{mystyle}
```

and the value is accessible by

```
\cs{myArray[0]}
```

You can declare a counter by `\newcount\mycount` and then you can extend the example above by replacing the `0` character by `\the\mycount`:

```
\newcount\mycount

\sdef{myArray[\the\mycount]}{mystyle}
\cs{myArray[\the\mycount]}
```

Comment: It's a cool idea to define a function in order to limit the heavy usage of `\csname`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're afraid of the access time to a sequence, you can use `\csname`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newarray}{m}
  {
    % keep the next free index
    \int_new:c { g__tobias_array_#1_int }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtoarray}{omm}
  {
    \tobias_array_add:enn
      {% the index
        \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
          { \int_eval:n { \int_use:c { g__tobias_array_#2_int } } }
          { \int_eval:n { #1 } }
      }
      { #2 } % the array
      { #3 }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getarray}{mm}
  {
   \tobias_array_get:ne { #1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 } }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tobias_array_add:nnn
 {
  \tl_gclear_new:c { g__tobias_array_#2_#1_tl }
  \tl_gset:cn { g__tobias_array_#2_#1_tl } { #3 }
  \int_gset:cn { g__tobias_array_#2_int } { #1 + 1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobias_array_add:nnn { e }

\cs_new:Nn \tobias_array_get:nn
  {
    \tl_if_exist:cT { g__tobias_array_#1_#2_tl }
      {
        \tl_use:c { g__tobias_array_#1_#2_tl }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobias_array_get:nn { ne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newarray{myarray}
\addtoarray{myarray}{An item}
\addtoarray{myarray}{Another item}
\addtoarray[1+3]{myarray}{Item \#4}

0: \getarray{myarray}{0}

1: \getarray{myarray}{1}

3: \getarray{myarray}{3}

4: \getarray{myarray}{2+2}

\end{document}
```

You can add to an array sequentially or even jumping over some indices. And do arithmetic in order to find or set an index.

In the example, the next `\addtoarray` would use index 5.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this LaTeX3 alternative! It's cool to be able to do arithmetic directly in the function.