# Command name containing a number

Tags: fonts, renewcommand

I want to define a command `\C4` which produces **C4** (both in bold and normal fonts). I wrote something like

```
\begin{document}
 \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textscn}{\upshape\bfseries}
 \newcommand{\C4}{\textscn{C4}}
\end{document}
```

This code gives an error. I wonder how can I avoid this error ?!.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot define commands having both letters and digits in their name. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598250/4427

Comment: One commonly used solution is to write the number using roman numerals (which are letters). Thus, `Civ`. Case-sensitive. Be sure tha the desired command is not already used by a package.

Comment: `\newcommand{\C}[1]{\textscn{C#1}}`  would allow `\C4`  and `\C5`  etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not have commands with numbers in their name

You could have

```
\newcommand{\C}[1]{\textscn{C#1}}
```

defining `\C` to take an argument so `\C4` or `\C3` would work, as would `\C{hello world}`

However I would avoid 1-letter commands, most are pre-defined in latex for accents and similar commands. For example if you start using `\C` you might be tempted to need `\c` for a lowercase version but `\c` is the cedilla accent.

I would use a slighly longer name such as

```
\newcommand{\upC}[1]{\textscn{C#1}}
```

which would allow `\upC4` and `\upC5`

or a name based on the semantic meaning, whatever that is. For example:

```
\newcommand{\category}[1]{\textscn{C#1}}
```

which  would allow `\category4` and `\category5`  if C4 stood for "category 4" in your real context.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax rules of TeX allow you to do

```
\def\C4{\textscn{C4}}
```

**BUT** you're **NOT** defining a command whose name is `C4`; you're defining the command `\C` which is *required* to be followed by `4`.

So, for instance, you cannot have also `\C3`.

You find very interesting posts at [*Why* does TeX not allow numbers in command names?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598250/4427) about the subject.

It is actually possible to make `\C` into looking for an integer following it and branch according to the value, but this is quite fragile and not recommended.

I'd simply choose `\Civ` or `\Cfour`.

Comment: How many times have you already explained this fact on this network?